# Bot Framework SDK4 - 'deploy.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: azure, gitlab, botframework

I am trying to set up automatic deployments from my GitLab instance to Azure for the Bot Framework SDK4. I am following [this guide.](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/auto-deploying-to-azure-app-services-from-gitlab/)
When I am trying to sync my changes from gitlab to azure I am getting the following error:

```
Command: deploy.cmd
'deploy.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'deploy.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\78.11022.3613\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd deploy.cmd
```

I have tried this on multiple azure instances and I have ran into the error on both. Any idea what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there is something trying to customise your deployment, you should find a .deployment file in your repository. you might have had this if you downloaded the original code from the Azure demo. removing this file from your repository should allow you to sync the code

if you want to restore the .deployment file at a later date the following link from the project kudu repo https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments should help. You can also download/copy the deploy.cmd file from your Azure directory and add it to your repository